# What is the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-usage

> 1. He is regularly buying food in the market.
> 2. He regularly buys food in the market.

It seems they all refer to the same thing that 'he buys food in the market regularly'? what's the difference?

Comment: I'll try to show it this way: **He's regularly buying food in the market. Everytime I'm there I see him do that. He seems to never have enough food.** and **He regularly byus food in the market. He's doing the right thing. He tries to have his fridge filled.**

Comment: The first phrase may imply a sort of annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple present should be used for discrete actions that occur regularly, habitually, or repeatedly:

> He regularly *buys* food from the market
>
> He habitually *take*s a shower every morning
>
> He repeatedly *checks* his phone whenever he is out of the house.

The present progressive is used for actions happening in the moment:

> Look.  He *is checking* his phone, again.
>
> He isn't home -- he *is* out *buying* groceries from the market.
>
> It's morning, so he *is taking* a shower.

**However** the present progressive *can* be used to indicate actions that happen so frequently it seems like they happen *all the time*.  In this case the sentence should include an adverbs like *always*, *continuously*, *constantly*, *nonstop*, and so on.

> He is *constantly* checking his phone when he's out of the house.  It's so annoying!
>
> He is *always* eating at restaurants instead of buying food from the market.

As with many things in language, the adverb-verb combination has to make sense.  Since *regularly* means *at regular intervals*, combining it with the present progressive is confusing.  It's a contradiction to say that something happens *regularly* then imply it happens *all the time*.

To be clear: it's grammatical, and possibly something people say without thinking too much about it, and the intention is clear.  But it sounds like a poorly constructed sentence, or something a non-native speaker might say.

Answer (score 2):

The second way, with the simple-present, would be the normal way to express this. The sentence expresses a fact about the person, that doesn't change.

The first sentence is slightly odd. It suggests that the regular event is temporary. It could emphasise a change to the market

> Since the supermarket shut he is regularly buying food in the market.

Or maybe to emphasise the change to regularity:

> He used to go shopping whenever He ran out of food. But since the baby came I need to be more organised. Now he is buying food in the market regularly.

As is usual, the present continuous can imply the changing or temporary nature of an action.